# Is it possible to use `let in` in an instance clause?

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
import Prelude hiding (Either (..))

data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
  show t = show ST t

data ShowableTree a = ST Int (Tree a)

instance Show a => Show (ShowableTree a) where
  let
    indent 0 = ""
    indent n = "\t" ++ (indent n-1)
  in
    show (ST depth Empty) = (indent depth) ++ "()"
    show (ST depth (Node n l r)) =
      let
        stl = ST (depth+1) l
        str = ST (depth+1) r
      in
        (indent depth) ++ "(\n" ++ (indent depth) ++ (show n) ++ "\n" ++ (show stl) ++ "\n" ++ (show str) ++ "\n" ++ (indent depth) ++ ")\n"
```

This spits out errors:

```
[m@green09 ~]$ ghci labn.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( labn.hs, interpreted )

labn.hs:14:3:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Let's try `where` perhaps?

```
instance Show a => Show (ShowableTree a)
  where
    show (ST depth Empty) = (indent depth) ++ "()"
    show (ST depth (Node n l r)) =
      let
        stl = ST (depth+1) l
        str = ST (depth+1) r
      in
        (indent depth) ++ "(\n" ++ (indent depth) ++ (show n) ++ "\n" ++ (show stl) ++ "\n" ++ (show str) ++ "\n" ++ (indent depth) ++ ")\n"
    where
      indent 0 = ""
      indent n = "\t" ++ (indent n-1)
```

Still no success:

```
[m@green09 ~]$ ghci labn.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( labn.hs, interpreted )

labn.hs:19:5: parse error on input `where'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

One clear solution is to pollute the global scope by moving the definition of `indent` to the global scope.

Barring this, however, is it possible to somehow define `indent` within `ShowableTree`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of an instance declaration is not an arbitrary expression; it's a list of function definitions. `let` can only be used where an expression is expected, and  `where` has to be associated with a single equation. However, it's simple enough to define `show` with a single equation that would allow you to use either.

```
-- using where
instance Show a => Show (ShowableTree a) where
    show (ST depth t) = case t of
                         Empty -> indent depth ++ "()"
                         Node n l r -> let stl = ST (depth + 1) l
                                           str = ST (depth + 1) r
                                       in  indent depth ++ "(\n" ++ indent depth ++ show n ++ "\n" ++ show stl ++ "\n" ++ show str ++ "\n" ++ indent depth ++ ")\n"
        where indent = flip replicate '\t'

-- using let
instance Show a => Show (ShowableTree a) where
    show (ST depth t) = let indent = flip replicate '\t'
                        in case t of
                             Empty -> indent depth ++ "()"
                             Node n l r -> let stl = ST (depth + 1) l
                                               str = ST (depth + 1) r
                                           in  indent depth ++ "(\n" ++ indent depth ++ show n ++ "\n" ++ show stl ++ "\n" ++ show str ++ "\n" ++ indent depth ++ ")\n"
```